# Connection failed: Connection refused... for MySQL database from PHP code, but I can connect from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

So I can login to phpmyadmin just fine from a web browser. But when I try to use the same username and password from my PHP code to login I get "**Connection failed: Connection refused**". I am running my LAMP stack on an Ubunutu terminal via Google Cloud.

If I change the servername from "127.0.0.1" to "localhost" I get "**Connection failed: Access denied for user 'cadeuser '@'localhost' (using password: YES)**"

This method of doing it works on my local machine (which I have an entirely different MySQL database with XAMPP), but not with the Google Cloud one. I am very new to this so go easy please.

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$myfile = fopen("../../reach.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

$username = fgets($myfile);
$password = fgets($myfile);

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Running "IFCONFIG" I get

```
ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.128.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe80:2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 42:01:0a:80:00:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 107514  bytes 176647898 (176.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 100127  bytes 15653331 (15.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6153  bytes 564232 (564.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6153  bytes 564232 (564.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is my phpmyadmin users
[view users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nrz9.png)

Here is my firewall stuff on Google Cloud [firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORpDg.png)

**SOLUTION**
I fixed it by adding "skip-grant-tables" under [mariadb] or [mysqld] at `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

I assume because the googlecloud one has a different IP address, or possibly your firewall might be preventing you. Try `ifconfig` and/or look at your firewall `ufw`. Also have you given the user 'cadeuser' full permissions?

Comment: I edited my original post with the results from "ifconfig". I'm not sure how to check the firewall, ufw didn't work for me. And "cadeuser" has ALL PRIVILEGES